# Wordpress Comment Loop on blog page

Tags: php, wordpress

i would like to add a comment form and display the latest comment for each blog post on the main blog loop so i have used this code and added it in the main blog loop after the content.

`global $withcomments;
$withcomments = 1;
comments_template( '', true );`

but it displays only on the first blog post and not on the other ones. 
I would like the form to be displayed on all the blog posts in the loop and only display the latest comment.

To be more exact as seen in the screenshot below, on the first post the comment textarea appears with the button and on the second post the textarea does not appear with the buttons despite the fact that the code was added in the loop.

[Comment form not showing properly - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DXb5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [get_comments()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) function.

In get_comments, you can set `order` parameter as 'desc'. so you get result in  descending order.

```
<?php foreach (get_comments() as $comment): ?>
<!--Your Contents-->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```